# Mysql Auto-incrementing int of similar data

Tags: php, mysql, int, auto-increment

So this is more of a query of how one might go about doing this, I'm new to MySQL/PHP coding when it comes to more than the basics so I'm just wondering how one might set up an auto incrementing int where if two lastnames were the same it would count them. 
I was unable to find anything on it while searching online but an example would be:

in the database we have 5 users

```
 1. james smith 1   
 2. terry smith 2
 3. john smith 3
 4. jerry fields 1
 5. tom straus 1
```

When these users register I need an int to be created that john smith was the 3rd person to have the same last name of smith while jerry fields is the first person with the last name fields etc. How might one do that?

The form I made is one that registers a user using a jquery/php ajax method but 
I would like to add something similar to this so that it combines that number with their names to make a specific user ID.

Comment: you can set autoincrement in your table and they will always have unique id, also u can write name and second name to different columns and count it by *select* query

Comment: Ya I do have each row autoincremented already, that would be the simple way of doing it, but my interest is just knowing how to have a separate int column based on similiar last names by order of registration. like the example above it auto counts the smith to 3 but sees fields and starts back at 1. but if another smith came in later it would be at 4. maybe its too complicated, I was thinking that this would have to be done in the php script reading mysql for how many times the same name occured then counting up one and posting to the column.

Comment: another word you need to know registration order of peoples with the same second name?

Comment: yes, and then posted to a column.

Comment: Do you want to create a [Trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) after each insert that would update the 'int column' after each insert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented under [Using `AUTO_INCREMENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-auto-increment.html):

> For `MyISAM` and `BDB` tables you can specify `AUTO_INCREMENT` on a secondary column in a multiple-column index. In this case, the generated value for the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column is calculated as `MAX(auto_increment_column) + 1 WHERE prefix=given-prefix`. This is useful when you want to put data into ordered groups.

Therefore, you could do:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  firstname VARCHAR(31) NOT NULL,
  lastname  VARCHAR(31) NOT NULL,
  counter   BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (lastname, counter)
) Engine=MyISAM;

INSERT INTO my_table
  (firstname, lastname)
VALUES
  ('james', 'smith' ),
  ('terry', 'smith' ),
  ('john' , 'smith' ),
  ('jerry', 'fields'),
  ('tom'  , 'straus')
;
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c3f7/1/0).

Comment: thanks, that actually works perfectly! Didn't know about setting the primary key to two separate columns.

Comment: what if you delete one row e.g with counter 1, next insert rows will be with counter 4, is it good?