# Update float column but retain its decimal - resequence an index to remove gaps

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this:

```
name     |   index
item A   |   1
item B   |   3
item C   |   3.2
item D   |   3.3
item E   |   30
item F   |   30.1
```

How can I resequence the index column using either mysql or php to remove all gaps in the integer sequence so that the table looks like this:

```
name     |   index
item A   |   1
item B   |   2
item C   |   2.2
item D   |   2.3
item E   |   3
item F   |   3.1
```

I have tried using `SUBSTRING` to replace the first digit in the index only but this doesn's allow for items E and F

Comment: "like this" - showing an example is not a proper description - especially if you don't list all the edge cases.

Comment: Given the nature of the task you're attempting to perform, it would appear that these values are not really fractional numbers at all—rather that they consist of two integers delimited by a `.` character, and just happen to be rendered like a fraction for display.  If so, you would probably be wise to store the value across two separate integer columns (combining together into a string, if so desired, at the presentation layer of your application).  Of course that wouldn't solve the problem in your question, but it at least begins to reduce it to a slightly simpler task.

Comment: Yes, you are correct @eggyal - it would have be better to store these as separate columns, however the application is quite mature and this is the last hurdle so I'd like to try to solve it if at all possible before resorting to a rewrite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [user-defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/user-variables.html) to keep track both of the last major part seen, and also of the current major-part with which to replace:

```sql
SET @new:=0, @old:=0;

UPDATE    myTable
SET      `index` = (@new := @new + (@old < (@old := `index` DIV 1))) + `index` MOD 1
ORDER BY `index`;
```

Explaining this from the inside out:

- The variables to be used are first initialised to zero.
- `` `index` DIV 1 `` gives the integer part of the current `index` value; this is assigned to `@old` so that it is available for the next record.
- It is compared against the *current* value of `@old` (i.e. from the previous record) using the `<` less-than operator; since MySQL does not have true boolean types, this expression evaluates to `1` if true and `0` if false—thereby providing a handy shortcut for incrementing `@new`.
- `@new` is updated with its new (i.e. incremented, if appropriate) value.
- `index` is updated with this value of `@new` plus the result of `` `index` MOD 1 ``, which is the fractional part of the original `index` value.
- The `ORDER BY` clause ensures that the updates are performed in the correct order.

However, given the nature of the task you're attempting to perform, it would appear that these values are not really fractional numbers at all—rather that they consist of two integers delimited by a `.` character, and just happen to be rendered like a fraction for display.

If so, you would probably be wise to store the value across two separate integer columns (combining together into a string, if so desired, at the presentation layer of your application).

One can provide a migration path without causing much interruption to the existing codebase by using a [view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/views.html) to simulate the old table structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE myNewTable LIKE myTable;

ALTER TABLE myNewTable
  ADD COLUMN index_major INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  ADD COLUMN index_minor INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL;

INSERT INTO myNewTable
SELECT   myTable.*,
         @new := @new + (@old < (@old := `index` DIV 1)),
         CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`index`, '.', -1) AS UNSIGNED)
FROM     myTable, (SELECT @new:=0, @old:=0) init
ORDER BY `index`;

ALTER TABLE myNewTable
  DROP COLUMN `index`;

ALTER TABLE myTable
  RENAME TO archived_myTable;

CREATE VIEW myTable AS
SELECT ..., CONCAT(index_major, '.', index_minor) AS `index` FROM myNewTable;
```

The application can then read (and update, except for the synthesized `index` column) this `myTable` view as if it were the original `myTable`—i.e. without any knowledge of the underlying change that has taken place.  `INSERT` statements, however, will need to be modified to work with the new underlying `myNewTable` instead.

Comment: Possibly relevant: [auto-incrementing within groups](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14321302).